# ResourceBundle cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: localization, internationalization, locale, resourcebundle

My Code is like:

```
package test;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class InternationalizationTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ResourceBundle bundle1 = ResourceBundle.getBundle("TestBundle");
    displayValues(bundle1);

    Locale defaultLocale = Locale.getDefault();
    ResourceBundle bundle2 = ResourceBundle.getBundle("TestBundle", defaultLocale);
    displayValues(bundle2);

    Locale swedishLocale = new Locale("sv", "SE");
    ResourceBundle bundle3 = ResourceBundle.getBundle("TestBundle", swedishLocale);
    displayValues(bundle3);

    Locale nonexistentLocale = new Locale("xx", "XX");
    ResourceBundle bundle4 = ResourceBundle.getBundle("TestBundle", nonexistentLocale);
    displayValues(bundle4);

}

public static void displayValues(ResourceBundle bundle) {
    System.out.println("hello message:" + bundle.getString("my.hello"));
    System.out.println("goodbye message:" + bundle.getString("my.goodbye"));
    System.out.println("question message:" + bundle.getString("my.question"));
    System.out.println();
}
```

}

But I am not able to import these two pakages:

```
 import java.util.Locale;
 import java.util.ResourceBundle;
```